# Show that $T=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a sufficient statistic for $p$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, estimators, bernoulli-distribution, sufficient-statistics

I try to use the definition of sufficient statistic to prove that

> Suppose that $X_1,\dots, X_n$ is an iid random sample from $X\sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(p)$. Show that $T=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a sufficient statistics for $p$.

The definition of sufficient statistics is that if the conditional joint distribution of the sample $(X_1,\dots, X_n)$ given $T$ does not depend on $\theta$.

---

My work:
Note that
$$
P(X_1=x_1,\dots, X_n=x_n|T=t)=\frac{P(X_1=x_1,\dots, X_n=x_n, T=t)}{P(T=t)}
$$

I'm not sure if my numerator and denominator are correct.

I do not know what is the numerator part.

But the denominator part is the sum of Bernoulli random variables, which is equivalent to the Binomial distribution.
$$
P(T=t)=\binom{n}{t}p^t(1-p)^{n-t}
$$

Comment: $P(T=t)=\binom{n}{t}p^t(1-p)^{n-t}$ looks reasonable.  What have you tried for $P(X_1=x_1,\dots, X_n=x_n, T=t)$?  Or perhaps for $P(X_1=x_1,\dots, X_n=x_n)$? Or since they are iid for $P(X_1=x_1)\cdots P( X_n=x_n)$

Comment: What is $t$? Use that as Henry showed what the numerator is. You have used the definition correctly.